# Doctest da error "Failed example" en "expected", siendo "expected" y "got" iguales

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

Este es el error:

```
File "pruebas.py", line 10, in __main__.listaraicescuadradas
Failed example:
    listaraicescuadradas(lista)
Expected:
    [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]         # la funcion devuelve un valor Double.
Got:
    [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

No comprendo por qué me falla el doctest si los valores son exactamente iguales.

El código es:

```
import math 

def listaraicescuadradas(Listanumeros):
    """ 
    la funcion devuelve una lista con la raiz cuadrada
    de los elementos pasados en otra lista por argumentos.

    >>> lista = []
    >>> for i in [4, 9, 16]:
    ...     lista.append(i)
    >>> listaraicescuadradas(lista)
    [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]         # la funcion devuelve un valor Double.


    """

    return [math.sqrt(n) for n in Listanumeros ]


import doctest

doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues, aunque no lo creas, el problema es el comentario que has puesto en esta parte:

```
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0]         # la funcion devuelve un valor Double.
```

Quítalo e intenta de nuevo con el código actualizado:

```
def listaraicescuadradas(Listanumeros):
    """ 
    la funcion devuelve una lista con la raiz cuadrada
    de los elementos pasados en otra lista por argumentos.

    >>> lista = []
    >>> for i in [4, 9, 16]:
    ...     lista.append(i)
    >>> listaraicescuadradas(lista)
    [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
    """

    return [math.sqrt(n) for n in Listanumeros ]
```

Por defecto los comentarios son ignorados pero, al parecer, esto no aplica cuando comentas la parte del código que devuelve el resultado a comparar.